# Cordova App not loading local assets

Tags: android, angular, cordova, assets

I am currently trying to port an Angular-Application to Cordova. My experience in Cordova is limited, most of the things I tried seem to work, but there is one major issue I am facing. All Assets are not loading, except those from external Sources (my Backend).

This is my config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.timmaex.app" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>CheckMeTest</name>
    <description>
        Test Application
    </description>
    <author email="censored" href="censored">
        Me
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <access launch-external="yes" origin="tel:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="6.2.1" />
    <engine name="browser" spec="^5.0.3" />
</widget>
```

I made an AOT Build with Angular cli and moved the dist folder to the www/ folder in my Cordova project, including the assets.

And there we go, it compiles and runs just fine. I can do everything but load my local assets on Android. Why is this, and what do I have to do about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate the app inside browser by adding browser platform, and then check what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I used the source as

> src="../assets/imgs/logo.png"

then I changed it to

> src="assets/imgs/logo.png"

removed any '../'

Answer (score 0):

Its simple in place of base we kept "./" so in the same way wherever you use assets you should specify like eg: "./assets/img.png". In my case it worked.[Angular Screenshot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ3J8.png) [Cordova Generated apk installed on Virtual Android Machine Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PGd8.png)

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/skyscrapers(450).png" /> <!--Usage of assets folder-->
<base href="./"> <!--Base Link in Generated index.html from Dist folder->
```